# Change growth ratios for panes inside SplitPane

Tags: java, javafx

Have an horizontal split pane. If the pane grows, then the two interior panes will grow equally (if the split pane grows 100 pixels then each interior pane grows 50 pixels).

Is it possible to adjust this so that the second interior pane grows more than the first one? Like the first one gets 25% of the growth and the second gets 75%.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc your link provides a Swing tutorial, but Voldemort asked for the JavaFX SplitPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SplitPane` has no direct API for this, but indirectly we may achieve this..

The [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html) gives us a hint:

> The dividers in a SplitPane have the following behavior: [...]
>
> - Dividers moving to the left/top will stop when the node's min size is reached.
> - Dividers moving to the right/bottom will stop when the node's max size is reached.
>     [...]

So, by setting a minimum size, we can force the SplitPane to distribute the available space as we need it.

This is a little example with two `TableView`s aligned left and right in a `SplitPane`. Now I bound the minimum size of the left `TableView` to 20% of the `Stage`s current width and the right ones to 70%.

```
TableView<?> table1 = createTable();
TableView<?> table2 = createTable();
table1.minWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty().multiply(0.2));
table2.minWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty().multiply(0.7));

SplitPane split = new SplitPane(table1,table2);
```

You can easily modify the minimum size, to constant values or bind them to different parent container sizes.